# php - prepared statement not executing

Tags: php

So I have this php that I am using to validate a form that would be submitted. it takes a Name and ID that the User generates, and checks it against a database.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require 'connection.php';
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password) or die("Error connecting to database: ".mysqli_error());
mysqli_select_db($conn,$database) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

$PName=$_POST['Name'];
$PID=$_POST['ID'];
$query = $PID;

$min_length = 0;
if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){          
    $query = htmlspecialchars($query);        
    $query = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$query);
    $raw_results = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT DISTINCT `Person_ID` FROM `Person_DT` WHERE `Person_ID` LIKE '%".$query."%'")" or die(mysqli_error($conn));

    if(mysqli_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ 
    // this section was omitted to make the post shorter
    // i.e. this reissues the previous form, but has all the previous information the user submitted
    }
else{// this is the bit where I am having trouble
$addstmt=mysqli_stmt_prepare("INSERT INTO Person_dt (PName,PID) VALUES (?,?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param('ss',$PName,$PID);
mysqli_stmt_execute($addstmt);
printf("%d Row Inserted.\n",$addstmt->affected_rows);
}
    }
else{ // if query length is less than minimum
        echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
}
```

So on running this code, I return 0 rows inserted. I also return no errors; Is there something wrong with my syntax? should I change to another method?

Comment: You have parse errors, as per posted.

Comment: mysqli_stmt_bind_param first parameter should be $addstmt

Comment: you have way too many unclosed questions, IMHO.

Comment: and your communications/PR skills need improvement. People expect the same type of "respect" when it comes to doing/saying something. You haven't said much in most of your posts. You seem to be the type to not do/say anything for solutions given. You take and run. You wanted your solution, there's a reward to be had for both parties.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, its just that I'm in the middle of the project and I'm in a rush to try and finish it. So if i came across as rude, I apologize. 

Furthermore, I just changed my code to include a statement initializer, and even followed the PHP manual's steps to setting up the statement, but I'm still coming across the same issue of the query not executing. I added some echo statements to end of the printf code to verify if the code is picking up the values that i want; which it is. is there a command or function that returns the preped statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not demoed the code, but looking at your example, I see a few typo-class issues that may be effecting your output. I'm noticing, at least in your posted code, that you have an extra quotation mark in line 14 after your mysqli_query closing parenthesis. Similarly, you don't close the parenthesis inside your prepare statement on line 21.

So, try again in line 21 with `$addstmt=mysqli_stmt_prepare("INSERT INTO Person_dt (PName,PID) VALUES (?,?)");` -- since the closing parenthesis here is part of the statement.

If you're looking for alternative methods, the object-oriented interface for mysqli() looks a little cleaner (see [The PHP mysqli docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php)). Personally, I prefer using PDO (docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)).

Good luck! I hope the solution is as simple as quote control.